# Loading splash screen via angular (HTML)

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, splash-screen

I have a splash screen created in HTML5 and jQuery. I want to load it using angular. But I get an error -  WARNING: Tried to load angular more than once.

```
Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its
detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help,
check http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.
```

my js:

```css
  angular.module('app')
    .controller('SplashCtrl',['$scope', 'cordova',
    function ($scope,$window,cordova,$location){
  
      /*Uncomment this for device*/
      // cordova.ready.then(function () {
      //   console.log('Cordova is ready');
      //   console.log("Ready....");
      // });


      $('#splash').ready() 
      {
        $('#main').load('views/splash.html');
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('#main').ready(function() {
                $('#splash').remove();
               window.location.href = "/#/login";
                console.log("path.." + path)
            });
        }, 2000);
      }

  }]); 
  
})();
```

app.js:

```css
(function () {
    'use strict';
   
    angular
        .module('app', ['ngRoute', 'ngCookies'])
        .config(config);
        

    config.$inject = ['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', '$httpProvider'];
    function config($routeProvider, $locationProvider, $httpProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/', {
                controller: 'SplashCtrl',
                templateUrl: 'views/splash.html',
                controllerAs: 'splash'
            })
            .when('/login', {
                controller: 'LoginCtrlr',
                templateUrl: 'views/login.html',
                controllerAs: 'login'
            })
            .when('/pay', {
                controller: 'PaymentCtrl',
                templateUrl: 'views/payment.html',
                controllerAs: 'pay'
            })
            .when('/scan', {
                controller: 'ScanCtrl',
                templateUrl: 'views/scan.html',
                controllerAs: 'scan'
            })
            .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });

            
            //$httpProvider.defaults.headers.post = {};
            $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*';
            //$httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*';



            $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['Accept'] = 'application/json';
            $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/json; charset=utf-8';
            $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['Access-Control-Max-Age'] = '1728000';
            
    }

})();
```

Comment: please share the HTML part

Comment: How are you loading AngularJS? On a side note, its not the best idea to use jQuery with Angular.

Comment: You have only shared the getter: `angular.module('app')`. Also share where the setter is: `angular.module('app', [])`.

Comment: The way how you define the controller on line #2 is not correct. change it into this code --> .controller('SplashCtrl',['$scope', '$window', 'cordova', '$location',

Comment: I think it's more like something you write inside your component HTML. ie: <hero-detail>Loading...</hero-detail>

Comment: ok, added all that you guys have asked for. Also, can you guide me how to do it in AJS isntead if jquery?